# docker ps show container is up. but docker exec show it is not running

Tags: docker, kubernetes, etcd

Background information：My k8s cluster have some mistake.And kube-apiserver get wrong healthz status of etcd.So I want to know why.So I just want to exec to etcd container.I finally know there is not enough disk space （only 1G).

But why `docker ps` show this container is runing.but `docker exec` tell me it is not running.

```
# curl -k https://127.0.0.1:6443/healthz
...
[-]etcd failed: reason withheld
...
healthz check failed
```

[image]

here is docker info show:

```
# docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 37
  Running: 25
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 12
 Images: 13
 Server Version: 19.03.11
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64
 Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 15.67GiB
 Name: fp-2
 ID: ZBZW:QSKA:RAO6:NDF6:6BNC:WH3S:GSHO:OT5T:XWYX:WLZF:OJQ5:YA4O
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  192.168.1.111
  192.168.1.52
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://system.mirror.aliyuncs.com/
 Live Restore Enabled: true
```

The ultimate solution is to restart docker service, and it works.but why? It is a bug or something?

Comment: Are you using specific tutorial for setup?  have you tried increase memory for etcd container ?

Comment: @Malgorzata None. The cluster has been running normally for several weeks.

Comment: Have you tried increase memory for etcd container ? and then check if everything works properly ?